# Sorting array by child value

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have some decoded json data I'd like to sort in a specific order based on a child value. The decoded json file is structured like this:

```
Array
(
    [location] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10215235726
            [title] => demo title
            [media] => Array
                (
                    [nodes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 15129696952092
                                    [thumbnail_src] => thumb_15131.jpg
                                    [is_video] => 1
                                    [code] => BTg35sbvdfc
                                    [date] => 1494577207
                                    [display_src] => image_15131.jpg
                                    [video_views] => 318
                                    [caption] => Batman
                                    [comments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [count] => 2
                                        )
                                    [likes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [count] => 87
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [comments_disabled] => 
                                    [id] => 47484867964790738
                                    [thumbnail_src] => thumb_11536.jpg
                                    [is_video] => 
                                    [code] => BTmSAQghufS
                                    [date] => 1493745672
                                    [display_src] => image_11536.jpg
                                    [caption] => Aquaman
                                    [comments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [count] => 2
                                        )
                                    [likes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [count] => 73
                                        )
                                )
etc...
```

I'm outputting values without problem using the following:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.linktojson.com"), true);

foreach($json['location']['media']['nodes'] as $value) {
    echo $value['display_src'];
}
```

But now I'd like to sort the output based on likes (`[count]`). I've tried a couple of methods I [found in answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074354/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-child-array) already, but I can't seem to apply their solutions in a way that works for me. Right now I'm looking at this for sorting:

```
function custom_sort($a, $b) {
    return $a['count'] - $b['count'];
}

usort($json, 'custom_sort');
```

This throws **usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given**, also there are two `count` children (comments and likes) anyway so it probably wouldn't work because of that.

I'm fairly new to working with these types of arrays, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is unclear? `$data_array` is __not__ an array.

Comment: @u_mulder Sorry about that, copy and paste error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.linktojson.com"), true);

// sorting by comments count
usort($json['location']['media']['nodes'], 'sort_by_comments');

// OR sorting by likes count
usort($json['location']['media']['nodes'], 'sort_by_likes');

// sorting functions:
function sort_by_comments($a, $b) {
    return $a['comments']['count'] - $b['comments']['count'];
}

function sort_by_likes($a, $b) {
    return $a['likes']['count'] - $b['likes']['count'];
}
```

Comment: Aah! Cheers for that mate, so obvious now that I have the solution (as always).

Comment: what about the parameter $a and $b?i could not understand about the parameter.please explain it.

Comment: @lalithkumar `$a` and `$b` are names of parameters passed to  implementation of a sort function. Values of `$a` and `$b` are elements of array which is currently being sorted.